usage of 'as for' - is this phrase used for only one usage like regarding?

The result of a boxing match, as for a figure skating routine, is very subjective.

If we replace 'as for' with 'regarding', it seems to be not that natural.

The result of a boxing match, regarding a figure skating routine, is very subjective.

Is there any other usage or any other substitution phrase for 'as for'?

Agreeing with the answer by JamesK. It's a case of ellipsis coupled with a re-ordering of phrases and a slightly off use of for, which  results in a marginal sentence.
The questionable sentence in the original post is not a case of "as for" in the sense of "regarding,with respect to", which we see in this example:

As for the Q4 earnings, they will be reported soon.

The ellipsis is like this:

As [it is] for a skating routine, the result of a boxing match is very subjective.

As for why it is not a case of "as for", compare:

We must take care with these ficus plants, as with succulents, not to overwater them.

As for for in the original:

The result for a boxing match is very subjective.

I would use with there.

With a boxing match, the result is very subjective, as it is with a skating routine.


The 'routine' here means 'usual movement/typical performance' that figure skaters make during the competition?

A figure-skating routine is one in which  specified movements must be performed; these movements as performed by the skater  are judged and awarded points by a panel of judges.  The result is a matter of (averaged) opinion, just as in a boxing match that does not result in a knockout, the winner is the one who was awarded the most points (for landing punches, etc).

Compare "dance routine", a set of choreographed (scripted) steps.

It should be understood as something like

The result of a boxing match (as is also the case for a figure skating routine) is very subjective.

It is supporting the claim that boxing is subjective by comparing it to figure skating, which it assumes you already accept to be subjective.
The phrasing doesn't quite work for me. It took a couple of readings and a moment's thought to work out the meaning.

The 'routine' here means 'usual movement/typical performance' that figure skaters make during the competition?

Routine as in "dance routine", or "comedy routine"  : a planned and choreographed sequence of dance moves (or jokes, or figure skating moves). A "set piece". This sense will be in the dictionary
